# Understanding function parameters

Tags: javascript

This probably has been asked before but all I can find are questions regarding C and Bash etc.

Basically I'm having a really hard time getting my head around function parameters and what they reference.

I know that you usually set paramters when you call the function e.g. `doSomething(3,'Hello')` etc, but when I read code from tutorials like so;

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
            setSquare(i);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support this script");
    }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare) {
    var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
    var colPlace = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4);
    var colBasis = colPlace[thisSquare] * 15;
    var newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;

    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
}
```

Where is `setSquare()` getting the parameter of `thisSquare` from?

Comment: Are you referring to the call `setSquare(i)`? I'm not entirely sure what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first function `initAll()`, you are calling setSquare(i). In this case, the `i` is the parameter. According to `initAll()`, `i` is a number in the `for` loop. Essentially what's happening is you're calling setSquare for each square number 0 to 24.

The `setSquare()` function has renamed the `i` to `thisSquare`. Now anywhere inside the `setSquare()` function, `thisSquare` is set to the same value that `i` had before.

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Pretty much perfect .... I love clear answers ... bravo ..... Just one more question if you don't mind with regards to setSquare(i), is that basically calling the function before the function has been created?

Comment: @17bc17: no, JavaScript interpreters "hoist" named `function` definitions to the top of the scope. So before actually running the code, the interpreter translates it into something like this: http://pastie.org/3157006

Comment: @PPvg - Thanks for the reply, its much appreciated. Do you have any links which explain this in more detail?, just I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @17bc17: [This question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting) is a pretty interesting read. Or MDN, of course: [MDN: Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting) and [MDN: Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `initAll` there is the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
   setSquare(i);
 }
```

So `initAll` is calling `setSquare` 24 times. Each time passing in the value of `i`. (0, 1, 2, etc.). So the value of `i` is `thisSquare`

Answer (score 0):

`setSquare` is being called in the `initAll` function, which passes it a value, from 0 to 23.  The `initAll` function is called when the page is loaded (in theory).

Answer (score 0):

It is getting it from the `for` loop in the `initAll()` function in this case, but it could get it from wherever you call `setSquare` function

Answer (score 0):

> Where is setSquare getting the parameter of thisSquare from?

Right here: `setSquare(i);`

Inside the setSquare function currSquare ends up being the id of a Dom element (for example, currSquare1).