# d3js tick function definition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I encountered a problem that I can not seem to understand, why if define tick function like this;

```
function tick () { /* do something */ }
```

It works fine and in this mode

```
var tick = function () { /* do something */ }
```

doesn't work. Where is the problem?

working example of first http://jsbin.com/omokap/10/edit

working example of second http://jsbin.com/isobul/1/edit

Comment: you misspelled "function" probably :)

Comment: There is a typo. `fucntion` should be `function`. If that's not the problem, then you are trying to use the function before it was defined. But to properly help you, you have to post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @GintasK `fucntion` is a typing error :D 

@FelixKling, i've added 2 example, please check if d3js library is added, because i've a problem with IPS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `tick` before its definition in one case and after its definition in the other case.

In the first case:

```js
force.on("tick", tick);

function tick () { /* ... */ }
```

the function `tick` is defined at parse time and is available to be passed as the second argument.

On the other hand in:

```js
force.on("tick", tick);

var tick = function () { /* ... */ };
```

the variable `tick` is defined at parse time (so JSHint does not complain), but it gets its value only at runtime. Its value is `undefined` when `force.on("tick", tick)` is executed.

The difference is more apparent when you consider the following example:

```js
var f;
if (true) {
    f = function () { return 1; };
} else {
    f = function () { return 2; };
}

f(); // returns 1
```

versus:

```js
if (true) { 
    function f () { return 1; }
} else { 
    function f () { return 2; }
}

f(); // returns 2, from the latest definition
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) to understand the difference between using the `var tick = function () ...` and `function tick() ...` better.