# What do I need to learn to develop with PoneGap and Sencha Touch?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am considering starting to explore PhoneGap and Sencha Touch to develop mobile applications.

I have found material regarding both frameworks.

Now, my question is: should I learn HTML5, JS, CSS before plunging into them or can I start without much knowledge about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice be you need to learn HTML5, JS, CSS before plunging into PhoneGap and Sencha touch.

**HTML5:** The following concepts need to be understood in HTML.
***DOM:***
Reference:[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), [w3 Org](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)
***Unicode:***
Reference:[what is unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
**JS:**
***Closure***
**Prototype Inheritance**
***Function as Objects***
***Javascipt Patterns***
References:[Design Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/),[Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript),[function scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)
**CSS:**
Reference:[CSS Intro](https://thomashunter.name/blog/introduction-to-css/)
The above are just a few essential things that you should learn before embarking on PhonegGap or any Javascript Framework

Comment: You missed one => SASS ;-).