# Why does TypeScript wrap class in anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's have, for example, a `Dog` class:

```
class Dog {
    static food;
    private static static_var = 123;

    constructor(private name) {}

    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + ', I eat ' + Dog.food + ', ' + Dog.static_var);
    }
}
```

Compiled to JS:

```
var Dog = (function () {
    function Dog(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
        console.log(this.name + ', I eat ' + Dog.food + ', ' + Dog.static_var);
    };

    Dog.static_var = 123;
    return Dog;
})();
```

This works equally well and is less complicated:

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log(this.name + ', I eat ' + Dog.food + ', ' + Dog.static_var);
};

Dog.static_var = 123;
```

Is there any (other than "aesthetic") reason for using the anonymous function wrapper?

Comment: `class` is an expression in typescript, isn't it?

Comment: I expect it is to limit the scope of whatever is defined within the class.

Comment: yes, that's why I tagged it typescript. Well, a keyword to be exact.

Comment: @bhspencer yes but it never puts any variable or anything into the scope

Comment: Yeah. I just looked through all the js that has been created in one of my TypeScript projects and don't see anything defined in the scope of the anonymous function. I am curious to see what the answer is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between the two has to do with [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting).

TypeScript compiles the class into an assignment of a function expression to a variable. That means the resulting constructor only starts to exist at the point of assignment. In the code that occurs before, `Dog` will be bound to `undefined`.

On the other hand, your implementation uses a plain function that is subject to hoisting -- any code in that scope, including code that occurs before the function, can invoke the `Dog` constructor.

I guess TypeScript prefers to ensure that a class does not exist before it is actually defined, possibly to allow redefining the class at several points in the same scope.

Comment: The only other thing I can add to this is that in big classes - not like the one provided in the question - minification will result in a smaller file as all variables in the closure will be minified.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon you mean *private* variables, I guess?

Comment: @MightyPork yes, and all of the class name references

Comment: oh right, that makes sense. A bit obscure reason, but valid too

Comment: Something like AngularJS (which in the next version is going to be written in TS) would benefit from this rather largely...

Comment: To prevent hosting, we can use the simple way `var Dog=function(){}`, I still can't understand why using more complicated way, wrapped in anonymous function.