# Does Javascript hoisting only consider the first var in a scope?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

In the following JavaScript code saySomething() writes "Hello there!" but not "Hello you!". Does this indicate that hoisting only applies to the first var within a scope?

```
var whatToSay = 'Hello World!';

function saySomething() {
  if (!whatToSay) {
    var whatToSay = 'Hello there!';
  }  
  document.write(whatToSay);
  var whatToSay = 'Hello you!';
}

saySomething();
```

Here is a link to the JS Bin http://jsbin.com/fiyimefeso/1/edit?js,output

Comment: This will probably help you understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Comment: @NormanBreau thank you but the link doesn't help me know why `var whatToSay = 'Hello there!'` takes precedence over `var whatToSay = 'Hello you!'`.

Comment: Hoisting only creates a variable, it doesn't do assignments.

Comment: JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

Comment: It doesn't "take precedence" but just happens that the variable value before the **write** is "Hello there". As dansasu said, its value is unrelated to the declaration. It doesn't magically grabs the last assignment and use it for the whole function but rather merely "Hello there" is the last held value before usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Hoisting means that var *declarations* happens before code execution. Var *assignments* happens during code execution. When hoisted, all variables has `undefined` values.

Proof here: http://jsbin.com/xezamexama/edit?js,output

Add type checking to comparison and it will print `undefined` and not `"Hello you!"` as you expected.

Comment: thank you, I hadn't considered assignment of separate of the hoisting process. Your answer explains what is happening well.