# Why `var a= function(){}` is similar to `function a(){}` in the following case?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand a part of the accpeted answer of this OP:

[Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Writer says:

"

Also, in this instance,

```
function a() {}
```

behaved the same as

```
var a = function () {};
```

".

What I know is that function expression is different than function declaration, at least for hoisting. Why are they similar in this case?

Comment: *"Does `var a= function(){}` always behave like `function a(){}`?"* - Definitely not.

Comment: :) I see @nnnnnn, my english didn't help formulate my question better. I am editing thanks

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Reread the answer; `function b()` is critical to understanding (in *scope*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I undestand now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are they similar in this case?

Because `var` is hoisted (but **not set**), like a *function declaration* is hoisted, meaning that there is an `a` in the local scope before `a = 10;` is evaluated, so the global `a` never gets modified - the identifier lookup finds the local `a` first so sets that

---

Related parts of the other question

```
var a = 1;

function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;

    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

> Why is `a === 1`?

---

That the answer was trying to say was that `b` is equal to

```
function b() {
    function a() {}
    a = 10;
    return;
}
```

Similar to

```
function b() {
    var a = function () {};
    a = 10;
    return;
}
```

i.e. there is an identifier `a` defined in `b`, so

```
function b() {
    var a = 10;
    return;
}
```

And now, obviously, the global `a` will not be modified by `b`

---

Please note that the position of the `var` isn't really important, just that it's there, the following will produce the same behaviour

```
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    var a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first line is defined at run-time, whereas second line is defined at parse-time for a script block.

Look at the full answer on stack, here : [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked question is really quite wrong. Strictly speaking, *neither* function is "defined" at parse time.

Comment: It would be best to flag the post as a duplicate instead of copying part of the answer here.

Comment: @anonymous : I actually can't access this option.

Comment: Oh, true. Still, I would be careful about doing this even without that ability. Maybe just move on to a different question to gain reputation first. But, there's not much point in doing that now, so no worries.

Comment: @anonymous : Ok, I understand.

Comment: @Pointy—I've given up trying to point out such subtleties of program execution, e.g. "hoisting" is a misnomer. To me, program execution is described clearly in [*ES5*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-10.4), the equivalent in [*ed 6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-executable-code-and-execution-contexts) seems more complex and less comprehensible.

Comment: thank you for this answer , even I don't fully understand , link and  comments will be of help for me to learn more. Please do you have any link or doc on these notions of run-time and parse time for javascript? thanks

Comment: @RobG sometimes I think the ES6 spec was designed as a level-up challenge since the ES5 spec was getting read by more and more people.