# Hoisting function expression

Tags: javascript, hoisting, function-expression

As far as I know only the declaration part of a function expression gets hoisted not the initialization.
E.g.:

```
var myFunction = function myFunction() {console.log('Hello World');};
```

So "var myFunction;" gets hoisted, but "function myFunction()..." not.

Now to my question, I played a little bit around with the google auth functions:

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready = (function() {
  var clientId = 'MYCLIENTID';
  var apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY';
  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts';

  $('#init').click(function() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth(false, handleAuthResult), 1);
  });

  var checkAuth = function checkAuth(imm, callback) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: imm
    }, callback);
  };

  var handleAuthResult = function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', initialize);
    } else {
      $('#progress').html('Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen');
    }
  };

  // Other code
})();
```

On line 10 "window.setTimeout(checkAuth..." I call the checkAuth function which is declared below this function call. My assumption was that I get an error saying "...checkAuth is not a function / undefined etc. ...", but instead it worked. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: *"As far as I know only the declaration part of a function expression gets hoisted not the initialization."* Function expressions don't have a declaration part. `var checkAuth = ...;` is a **variable declaration**. The value you assign doesn't matter. It can be a function (like here) or a number or something else. Variable declarations are hoisted.

Comment: `window.setTimeout(checkAuth(false, handleAuthResult), 1);` This must be written as `window.setTimeout(checkAuth.bind(null, false, handleAuthResult), 1);` and everything will be alright. More explanation below by other authors.

Comment: The order in the source code doesn't matter that much.The order in which the code is executed is what you need to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when an actual click event on the element is triggered, the **value** of `checkAuth` is *then* available in the scope. The error you expected would happen this way:

```
checkAuth(false, ...); // the symbol is available, but...

// its value is assigned here
var checkAuth = function checkAuth() {
    /* more code */
};
```

Notice the immediate invocation of `checkAuth()` *before* it's assigned in the above snippet.

What *is* available at the point of invocation is the *symbol* named `checkAuth`; its value, though, gets assigned later. Hence the error *checkAuth is not a function* rather than *checkAuth is undefined*.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In fact the symbol will  be available in javascript and the snippet will not throw the error you mention.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. But why is it available in the scope? The click function has its own scope, or not?

Comment: I am sorry, but I need to dig deeper. I still do not get why the value of checkAuth is available in the scope, when I use a click event? Can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Shimigami: Every function in JS is a closure. Every function has access to variables defined in a "higher" scope. `checkAuth` is defined in the same scope the handler is defined, hence the handler can access that function.

Comment: @lorefnon [Is that so?](https://jsbin.com/wivabulanu/edit?js,console) Shimigami, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7506937/255756) why the *symbol* is available, but its *value* is available later.

Comment: Ah My bad. I was testing for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9s0m539e/) . I did not acknowledge that the variable being assigned had the same name as the function.

Comment: OF COURSE! The compiler does all the declarations at first (var clientId etc.) and then executes the script: 1) Initializes clientId, apiKey and scopes variables 2) Adds the click event listener 3) Initializes the checkAuth variable 4) Initializes the handleAuthResult variable 5) Other code... When then somebody clicks the button, the checkAuth variable is already initialized (step 3). I did not take into account that the click happens later. Thank you!

Comment: If, in this example, you removed the 'var ' in front of the checkAuth=, you would have gotten a 'checkAuth not defined' error instead of a 'checkAuth is not a function' error.  That's because the var-phase didn't create the variable checkAuth at all, and it doesn't exist until the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration of a named function is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) from assigning a function to a variable. [This article](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) elaborates this in much detail with examples. I am quoting the important parts here for the sake of completeness:

> we first need to understand the distinction between a function
>   expression and a function declaration. As it’s name implies, a
>   function expression defines a function as part of an expression (in
>   this case assigning it to a variable). These kind of functions can
>   either be anonymous or they can have a name.
>
> ... a function declaration is always defined as a named function without
>   being part of any expression.
>
> ... the function expression can only be called after it has been defined
>   while the function declaration can be executed both before and after
>   it’s definition

You will get the error that you expected if you remove the function name :

```
 var checkAuth = function(imm, callback) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: imm
    }, callback);
  };
```

In addition you seem to be using setTimeout incorrectly:

```
window.setTimeout(checkAuth(false, handleAuthResult), 1);
```

Will execute the checkAuth immediately rather than delay it, if you want to delay the execution of checkAuth you can wrap it in an anonymous function :

```
window.setTimeout(function() { checkAuth(false, handleAuthResult) }, 1);
```

Comment: I tried to remove the function name, but it still works. Yes you are right, I should use an anonymous function within the setTimeout.

Comment: Once you add an anonymous function it will work because by the time the anonymous function runs the function has already been assigned to the variable. 

However if you try to execute it before assignment it will fail: Contrived example: 

`foo();  var foo = function() { alert('hello'); } ;`
`VM380:2 Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function(…)`

Comment: I tried to remove the function name and use an anonymous function, but still it works...

Comment: Yes that does not invalidate my answer. Please read my previous comment carefully, it contains the answer for your query.

Comment: If you do not use an anonymous function you will get the error.