# Why is `a` undefined in below function?

Tags: javascript

```
 a = 10;

function abc() {
 console.log(" a is " + a);
var  a =5;
console.log("after a is " + a);
}

abc();
```

In this code  above , my first console.log is showing `a` as undefined whereas the second console.log is showing the result of `a` as 5.

I am still trying to understand why my first console is showing `a` as undefined. I already defined variable `a` as a global variable.

Comment: Read about [_variable hoisting_](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 5):

```
function abc() {
 console.log(" a is " + a);
var  a =5;
console.log("after a is " + a);
}
```

this is turned into because of hoisting

```
function abc() {
 var a;
 console.log(" a is " + a); // undefined
a =5;
console.log("after a is " + a); // 5
}
```

javascript has lexical scope so the function will look for `a` in itself before looking outside and since it finds `a = 5` ,it will hoist it's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This because the variable `a` has been declared again. No matter at which line you declare, the variable a has block-level-scope .

The case is undefined because, var a at that time is declared but is not supplied with any value.

This is what we call as "***Hoisiting***" i.e.

> Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved
>   (“hoisted”) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the
>   JavaScript interpreter

Comment: `the variable a has block-level-scope` are you sure? javascript variables don't have block scope, they are function scoped.