# Why is it already a window property?

Tags: javascript, initialization

Why is foo a property of window when it's not used or initialized until a few lines later

```
for(var propName in window) {
    if(propName == 'foo') { //obv defined if its here
        console.log('WTF? Its already a part of window!!');
    }
}
console.log(typeof foo);
var foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually look like this one due to [var top hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

When you declared the variable globally it is part of ***this***  object implicilty.
So,your ***foo*** variable is part of `window` object which is refered by `this` object.

```
var foo;
for (var propName in window) {
    if (propName == 'foo') { //obv defined if its here
        console.log('WTF? Its already a part of window!!');
    }
}

console.log(typeof foo);
foo = 'bar';

this===window //true in this case
```

Comment: Thanks so much, had been trying figure this out for like hours. Knew it had to have a name.