# Variable Identification by JS in a simple program

Tags: javascript, debugging, variables, object

I have got a simple program which I am running first time in a browser. I am on *line 6*. When I am trying to find out values of **a**, **b** - the browser responds with value **'undefined'**. But when I am trying to find out value of **c**, which of course is not present it gives me an error.

My Question is when I am debugging at **line 6** - the status of ***b & c*** must be same - either both 'undefined' or both 'giving error', because for the program at line no 6, a exists - but ***both - b & c*** are ghosts at this state of program, then how is it giving b as undefined and c as error (which of coarse is correct). But, when did the program found out which variables am I using and which not, when I am still in mid, at first half of program, running it first time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScripts **hoists** variable declarations. That means that even before the code is executed, JavaScript will create bindings in the current environment for every variable declaration in the source and initializes them with `undefined`.

You can think of the evaluation order as:

```
  var a;
  var b;
> a = ...;
  b = ...;
```

where you are breaking on the third line.

There is no binding `c` in the current environment which is why it throws a ReferenceError.

See also [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7506844/218196) and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20hoisting).

Comment: Any standard link for documentation ?

Comment: If you want to read the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation step 16 for the global environment and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation step 27 and 28 for functions. Otherwise, various sources provide easier to understand explanations, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting, or https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch4.md, but they are not "standard".

Answer (score 1):

that is because hoisting.

as your variables a and b are declared in the script,js compiler will move them to top of the script while executing.

your code

```
var a=['apple','mango'];
var b=[{color:'red'}];
```

while executing compiler moves the declarations to top of the script.

```
var a;
var b;
a=['apple','mango'];
b=[{color:'red'}];
```

so when you access `a` or `b`,you will see `undefined` as their value.but still `c` is not declared.so you will get exception