# What will the reference be when a variable and function have the same name?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable named foo and function named foo.

```
//variable followed by function declaration
var foo="bar";
function foo(){
  return "bar";
}
//function declaration followed by variable
function foo(){
  return "bar";
}
var foo="bar";
//When I call foo it returns string bar;
//When I enquired foo() it throws error
```

What's happening here?Why does the variable name override function declaration?

Comment: both cases will return the string "bar".
basically functions are hoisted to the top of the file . 
so the string "bar" will replace them in both cases . 
-- it shouldn't return undefined it should raise an error .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *When I call `foo` it returns string `bar`;*

Function declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) to the top of their scope. The function definition are moved above by the compiler. And then the variable is overwriting to string.

Code is equivalent as

```
function foo() {
    return "bar";
}
// Overwriting the value
var foo = "bar"
```

So, in both the cases, the output will be `'bar'`.

Note that [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) are not hoisted.

For more information on function hoisting, see [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

> *When I enquired `foo()` it is `undefined`*

`foo` here is not a function, it's a string. So, `foo()` will throw an error

> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function(…)

Comment: @Tushkar it did throw an error, it's my mistake stating foo undefined. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a clearer and more explicit way of declaring variables, the latter will take account:

```
    var foo = "bar";
    var foo = function () {
        return "bar";
    };
    console.log(foo);
```

output is a function

and the reversal:

```
var foo = function () {
    return "bar";
};
var foo = "bar";
console.log(foo);
```

has "bar" as output.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions are processed upon entering the corresponding scope.
The variables are processed when the interpreter gets to their declaration.
Therefore in your example, the functions are processed first, the name `foo` is used by the last function and then overwritten by the variables.

Note that if you declare your function like this

```
var foo = function() {}
```

it is actually not processed at the beginning and also overwriting the variables declared beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo="bar";

var foo = function(){
  return "bar";
};
```

They are the same. Don't miss to put `;` in the end of line.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't answer the question and that missing `;` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

both cases will return the string "bar"

basically javascript grabs all functions and put them in the top of the file 
its called hoisting .

so the string declaration will overwrite the function expression in both cases ;