# multiple ADOBE ANIMATE CC buttons to control the timeline not working

Tags: javascript, html, animate-cc

I have to control the timeline of an animation for html5 canvas. I made all buttons and edited all codes. strangely all buttons execute the same function.

```
this.stop()
//---------------------------------------------------------//
this.letterA.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    this.gotoAndPlay(32);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------//

//---------------------------------------------------------//
this.letterB.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
}
function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    this.gotoAndPlay(212);
}
```

Comment: also, this code is "generated" by adobe CC. as I"m not a coder, just a meager animator, I just copied and pasted the same one editing the symbols' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [function hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting); the function statements are hoisted to the top-of-the-scope, so that your code is equivalent to

```
function fl_MouseClickHandler() {
    this.gotoAndPlay(32);
}

function fl_MouseClickHandler() {
    this.gotoAndPlay(212);
}

...
this.stop()    
this.letterA.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
this.letterB.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
```

---

One solution would be to use function expressions:

```
var that = this;
this.letterA.addEventListener("click", function () { that.gotoAndPlay(32); });
```

or if you insist to use `bind`

```
this.letterA.addEventListener("click", (function () { this.gotoAndPlay(32); }).bind(this));
```

Comment: I tried this:
this.stop();

var letterA = this;
this.letterA.addEventListener("click", function () {
 letterA.gotoAndPlay(97)
});
var letterB = this;
this.letterB.addEventListener("click", function () {
 letterB.gotoAndPlay(108)
});

and it seems to have worked. I"ll try it on the main file and see if it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are binding the same function to two different *button* click events. You have two different definitions of this same function. One is most likely being written over the other and therefore both buttons will call fl_MouseClickHandler which will call gotoAndPlay with the same timestamp.

Quick fix could be just to change the name of fl_MouseClickHandler:

```
function fl_MouseClickHandlerA() {
    this.gotoAndPlay(32);
}

function fl_MouseClickHandlerB() {
    this.gotoAndPlay(212);
}

this.letterA.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandlerA.bind(this));
this.letterB.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandlerB.bind(this));
```

Also, you should watch how you use "this" as you may not be scoped to what you think.