# Why does this anonymous function see what's under it?

Tags: javascript

Why can the first anonymous function 'see' the functions under it such as `foo`? Shouldn't it only see what it is above it? Thanks.

```
window.onload = function(){
    foo();
}

function foo(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Function (and variable) declarations are processed before any code is executed, also called "hoisting".

Comment: @Barmar Although the same language mechanism is at play, that other question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting):

> Function declarations in JavaScript are hoisting the function definition. You can use the function before you declared it:
>
> ```
> hoisted(); // logs "foo"
>
> function hoisted() {
>    console.log("foo");
> }
> ```

Comment: I'll blame caching in the mobile client then.

Comment: Not just *function* declarations, *variable* declarations (not the initialization value) are hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope as well. So, `var f = function(){...}` will hoist as well. Not the value (the function), but the variable (`f`).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [function hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting). In JavaScript, function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of their scope, which, as you noticed, allows functions declared anywhere in the file to be called.

Comment: Not just *function* declarations, all variable declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope as well. Not the assigned values, but the declarations.