# Block scope in js

Tags: javascript, scope

I was playing aroun and found interessting thing

```
var x = "x";
function a (){
    var x = "y";
  if(1){
    var x = "g";
    alert(x);
  }
  alert(x)
}

a()
```

why does this output "g" , "g"  insted of "g" , "y" ? The if creates another block scope and x is local variable inside it which means when i get out of the if block , the outer x ( which equals "y" ) should be printed.

Comment: Please search google. This has been answered many times. Also for block scope, use `let`. variables declared with `var` are hoisted

Comment: Variable hoisting http://stackoverflow.com/q/7506844/2942475

Comment: JS doesn't have block scope. It has function scope.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the variable x has a function level scope and the latest value set to the variable is "g". And so you it alerted twice with same value of x "g".