# Function declaration in a switch - Why does only the last definition remain?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I tried to implement a function using a switch, because I wanted to implement it differently, depending on the case. In a simple form, this is what it looks like:

```js
function test() { console.log('hello world'); };
someVar = 'foo';
switch (someVar) {
  case 'foo':
    console.info('foo');
    function test() { console.log('foo'); };
    break;
  case 'bar':
    console.info('bar');
    function test() { console.log('bar'); };
    break;
  default:
    console.info('default');
    function test() { console.log('default'); };
}

test();
```

Now, the console says `'foo'`, but if you have a look at the source code of `test`, it will be `function test() { console.log('default'); }`. This is not a scoping issue though, since a switch does not have its own scope, plus the function's first declaration is before the switch.

However, if `test` is declared as a `var` and initialized in the cases, the result will be as desired.

But why is always the last function declaration implemented, independent from which case is actually executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically all named functions are hoisted and the last one overwrites the first with the same name.

The result is something like

```
function test() { console.log('hello world'); };
    function test() { console.log('foo'); };
    function test() { console.log('bar'); };
    function test() { console.log('default'); }; // this is the last one and in use

    someVar = 'foo';
    switch (someVar) {
        case 'foo':
            console.info('foo');
        break;
        case 'bar':
            console.info('bar');
            break;
        default:
            console.info('default');
    }
}
```

For function, which changes on switch, you could use an assignment to a variable of a function expression, you need.

```
function test() { console.log('hello world'); };
    var test;

    someVar = 'foo';
    switch (someVar) {
        case 'foo':
            test = function () { console.log('foo'); };
            console.info('foo');
        break;
        case 'bar':
            test = function () { console.log('bar'); };
            console.info('bar');
            break;
        default:
            test = function () { console.log('default'); };
            console.info('default');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`function x() {}` *declarations* are *hoisted*; they're evaluated before the actual code is run. What you need to make this work is a function *expression* assigned to a variable:

```
var test = function () { ... };

switch (...) {
    case ...:
        test = function () { ... };
        break;
    ...
}
```

This will behave as expected, since it evaluates and explicitly reassigns the name `test` at runtime.

Comment: The dupe doesn't really explain "multiple hoisting", so may not fully answer the question.

Comment: Agreed. Then should we not post well explained answer over there as that post will be indexed higher and since its old post, it will have more discussion eventually giving more information?

Comment: Far be it from me to discourage de-duplication, but we don't have to merge everything with everything… :)