# Numeric-defined varliable becomes as NaN while trying to print json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to use the following code in order to split Json array into 3-columns Bootstrap rows
I'm trying that by increasing a numeric variable to 3, adding a new row div and set it back to 1.

actually, the variable return as "NaN" at the first attemt to increase it

please your help, or any other idea to splir json to 3-col rows.

the code:

```
 <script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    var coli;

    console.log( 'ready!'+coli );

   $.getJSON("games.json", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        var coli=1;
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            if (coli==3) {
                html += '<div class="row">';
                console.log( "3!" );
            }

           html += '<div class="col-md-4 img-portfolio">';
           html += '<a href="portfolio-item.html">';
           html += '<img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="'+value.teaser+'" alt="">';
           html += '</a>';
           html += '<h3>';
           html += '<a href="portfolio-item.html">'+value.title+'</a>' ;
           html += '</h3>';
           html += '<p>'+coli+value.description+'</p>';
           html += '</div> ';


             if (coli==3) {
                html += '</div>';
                var coli=1;
                console.log( "1!" );
            }
            coli++;
            console.log( 'ready!'+coli );
        });

    $('#yourContainerId').html(html);
    });

      });
   </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: remove the `var` inside your second `if`

Comment: You declare coli three times, just use the global one.

Comment: Variables defined with `var` are hoisted. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace

```
if (coli==3) {
    html += '</div>';
    var coli=1;
    console.log( "1!" );
}
```

with

```
if (coli==3) {
    html += '</div>';
    coli=1;
    console.log( "1!" );
}
```

You are declaring your variable coli new in the `if-statement`. That is what you should not do.

Comment: Your'e right! 
Did it while trying to fix it. Just removed the "var" and it starts working. also I had to set 1 as the initial variable and 0 and the resetting  at the and of the loop.