# why nested function scoped variable gives different error

Tags: javascript

I was running following JavaScript:

```js
var foo = function() {
  var a = 3,
      b = 5;
  var bar = function() {
    var b = 7,
        c = 11;
    a += b + c;
    console.debug(d);
  };
  bar();
  console.debug(c);
  var d = 10;
};
foo();
```

Clearly, `d` is not known to nested function `bar` and `c` is not known to external function `foo`. But in developer tools, when I load my web page I get two different logs one by one:

```
undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

Why are the errors different for the two cases? In my opinion both should have thrown simply thrown reference error if the corresponding variable is not known to them or is out of scope.

Comment: because `c` is in the function scope. Anything declared with `var` is not available outside the function. It is only available inside of it.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Comment: The dupe should explain it. [Var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) happens and `d` is actually declared but not initialized with a value at the beginning of the function because `var`s are functions scoped. Thus, you get undefined instead of a reference error for `d` inside `bar`. But since `c` only ever existed in `bar`, it's never accessible outside.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `c` died when function `foo` returned; `c` is local to `bar` because a `var` qualifier was used.

Comment: But variable `d` has been declared after the definition of function `bar` completes. So `d` should be equally dead (not have come to life yet) for `bar` function. Isn't it? I've *not* downvoted you.

Comment: This answer is really incomplete to the issue at hand. It doesn't address the main issue.

Comment: `d` is not dead because of hoisting.