# When does Global Variables take preference over Function Scoping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

**Case 1:**
The following Code alerts *10* as it should:

```
var globalId='10';  
function check(){  
    alert(globalId);  
}  
check();
```

**Case 2:**
But this next code alerts *undefined*:

```
var globalId='10';  
function check(){  
    alert(globalId); 
    var globalId; 
}  
check();
```

For **Case 2** the **solution** is :

```
var globalId='10';  
function check(){  
    var globalId; /**moved to top of the function due to hoisting and has an initial value of undefined. Hence, alert(globalId) return undefined. **/

alert(globalId); //undefined
var globalId; 
}  
check();
```

My question is now, how does in Case 1 `globalId` has the value of `10` ?

Comment: if there's no local, it starts looking outward until it gets to globals.

Comment: Because you havent declared a scope level variable in the first case

Comment: Because you make the var private in the case 2 with the prefix `var` inside the function...

Comment: variables declared using `var` are hoisted. You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 1):

Never. In JavaScript, variables declared in the current functional scope always take precedence over variables declared in the outer scope.

In your second example,

```
var globalId='10';  
function check(){  
    alert(globalId); 
    var globalId; 
}  
check();
```

The interpreter automatically moves your `var globalId` declaration to the top for you, which results in:

```
var globalId='10';  
function check(){  
    var globalId;
    alert(globalId);
}  
check();
```

and that's why it's showing `undefined`.

Comment: I don't think the interpreter moves anything. When creating an execution context, function and variable declarations are processed first, then code is executed, hence why declared variables and functions exist prior to code execution. I dislike the term "hoisting" because it infers that code is moved.

Comment: @RobG The term "moved" is used because it's easier to understand. You are absolutely correct that the line isn't physically moved (you are RobG after all ;) ) but all variable declarations will be performed before anything else in their context.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is now, how does in Case 1 globalId has the value of 10?

Because

- In JavaScript, variable are **function** (if declared with var) or **block** scoped (if declared with let or const).
- And you **haven't localized the scope of the variable** by using `var`, `let` or `const`.

So, it uses the scope in which the function `check` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is hoisting concept. See the links it will help you understand the concept [Scope & Hoisting](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) [One more good article](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/). **Happy Coding**