# Javascript:Call Method By using A Reference Vs Direct Method Invocation

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code:

```js
var a = function(){
    a.data = "10";
};
    
function a(){
    a.data = "20";
};
a();
console.log("a data::", a.data);
```

I feel that the output should be 20, but it's 10 instead. Please help me understand the output. I've removed `var` but it's still showing the same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are hoisted to the top, so when you reassign `a`, it happens after the declared function `a`.

Essentially this is happening to your code:

```
function a() { ... }
// other variables and functions
a = otherFunctionA;
a();
```