# Reference Error in javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating some basic plugin and i am getting Reference error. Below is my code

```
jQuery.fn.validate = function(options) {
  var _self = this;
   // with below call I gets reference error.
  abc();  

    //but if call in below it works fine
  _self.on("submit", function(event) {
     abc();  // works fine
  }),

 abc = function () {
   console.log('here);
 }
};
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to overcome it. As i need to call some reset and init functions at the begining of the plugin.

Comment: You're calling abc() before you have declared it, move the call to abc() below where you declare abc = function()

Comment: You shouldn't define global names in a plugin, you should make `abc` a local name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by local name ? Can you give me example ?

Comment: `var abc = ...` instead of just `abc = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're expecting `abc` to be [hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting), but you're specifically using a syntax that leaves `abc` undefined until the assignment is executed.

You need to move `abc = function ...` up above the invocations of `abc()`, *or* define the function using `function abc() { }` which will allow it to be hoisted above your invocations.

Note that, if you simply move the assignment,  you should use `var abc = function ...` and create a local variable, rather than the global `abc` variable you're currently creating.

Comment: ok i got your point but it works when i call _self.on("submit", function(event) {
     abc();  // works fine
  }),

Comment: @Amanjaura Because that is invoked after your assignment, at some point in the future when a button is clicked and that callback is invoked.

Comment: So which approach should i use in plugins while creating function           
`abc = functions` or `function abc()` ? Or is there any better solution on how to create and initialize functions in js plugin. Anyhow thanks for the above explanation.