# Why the second console.log() gives 2, insted of 1?

Tags: javascript

Why the second `console.log()` gives `2`, insted of `1`?

```js
function f() {
    console.log(2);
}

f();

(function() {
    f();
    f = function() {
        console.log(1);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to produce `1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Comment: This is more of a general scope question. Not really a JS specific.

Comment: It's definitely hoisting.

Comment: @Rhumbori I think this is different. That question is about hoisting, this one is simply misunderstanding of how this code is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure it's hoisting.

Comment: No, this isn’t a hoisting issue. In the IIFE, `f` isn’t declared with a function declaration (in which case the second log would indeed be `1`) or a `var` (in which case it would throw a TypeError). The same `f` is just reassigned, but the reassignment takes place _after_ both logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript function declarations are hoisted within enclosing scopes, but assignments are not. What you have in your second call is not a function declaration — you are just changing the value of an existing variable. If you wanted a hoisted version of `f()` in your second call you would need to do something like:

```js
function f() {
    console.log(2);
}

f();

(function() {
    f();
    function f() { 
       // this is a function declaration so it will be hoisted to the top
       console.log(1);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling f(); in the IIFE before your function expression. If you move your second f(); call below the expression you will get the result you are expecting.

```
function f() {
    console.log(2);
}

f();

(function() {
    f = function() {
        console.log(1);
    }
    f();
})();
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I think "before you assign a different function to `f`" would be more accurate.

Comment: hmmm, I think it does...? it's about where the function is called. Before the function expression, the f() invokes the function statement. After, it references the expression...

Comment: agreed. poor choice of words initially.

Answer (score 1):

The second "console.log(1)" outputs 2 because it is really the first "console.log(2)" that you are calling — twice. You never actually called the function that would trigger "console.log(1)". Here's a more representative example of what is happening:

```js
function f(value) {
    console.log(value);
}

f('a');

(function() {
    f('b');
    f = function() {
        console.log('c');
    }
    // unless you call "f()" at this point, this would not work. The "f = func ... " doesn't get hoisted.
})();
```

Notice how the output is "a" and "b", but "c" is never logged. Variable assignments of functions don't get hoisted, I'm assuming that you would thought would happen?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the **function declaration** is getting executed twice.

FYI - function declaration gets hoisted but function expression does not.

```js
function f() { // function declaration
  console.log(2);
}

f(); // 2

(function() {
  f(); // 2

  f = function() { // function expression
    console.log(1);
  }

  // you can use function expression here now that it is defined
  f(); // 1

})();

// will output:
// 2
// 2
// 1
```

Read up:

- [Hoisting - Glossary | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)
- [function expression - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)
- [function declaration - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)