# duplicate a row of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

duplicate the row of an array retrieve the same data (javascript) I tried that but it adds an empty line in vuejs.

folders is may table

```
function(folder) {
    this.folders.push(folder);
    folder={
        employee:"this.employee", 
        contact:"this.contact", 
         endContact:"this.endContact", 
        enterp:"this.enterp", 
        dossi:"this.dossi", 
        status:"this.status"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Comment: (1) is the function anonymous on purpose ? (2) you should not reassign a function parameter. (3) you assign folder and return, which makes the assignation useless.

Comment: I do'nt understand can you make me an example thank you

Comment: I just want to duplicate the same line in a table I can not do it