# I recently came across this code snippet . This code prints JavaScript as output. I don't know the reason Why?

Tags: javascript

Came across this question recently the output of the code mentioned below is JavaScript curious how .

```js
var name = "JavaScript"
function foo() {
    name = "Developer";
    return;
    function name() {
    }
}
foo();
console.log(name) //Javascript
```

Comment: Correctly formatting the code might help alleviate your confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Comment: This has to do with function hoisting. The `name` function inside `foo` is implicitly moved to the top, so the inner `name` "variable" is actually a reassignment of the reference that points to the empty function.