# Why is this variable 4？

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(window.b,b) //undefined undefined
if(true){
    console.log(b) //ƒ b(){} does it get hoisted?
    b = 4
    function b(){}
    b = 3
    console.log(b) //3  Why is this variable 3
}
console.log(window.b,b) //4 4   Why is this variable 4
```

If the code removes this line

```
function b(){}
```

The browser will report an error `VM114:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined` at line 1 `console.log(window.b,b)`

Can someone tell me why it works like this？？

if `function b` gets hoisted, does it equals to

```js
console.log(window.b,b) //undefined undefined why it doesn't cause an ReferenceError b is not defined
if(true){
    function b(){}
    b = 4
    b = 3
    console.log(b) // 3
}
console.log(window.b,b)  // ƒ b(){} ƒ b(){}
```

I am not a native English speaker,hope you can understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Comment: Check this out. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: I was mistaken, hoisting works in both local/global (or script) scope

Comment: Hoisted should become: var b; b=4; b=function(){}; b=3;

Comment: Function declarations inside `if` blocks have always been kinda wonky. [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) disallows this for that reason; which I recommend you always use.

Comment: Also can you add information about the browser error when you remove the b function line? Can you tell us if you’re in strict mode or not?

Comment: @Zorgatone  I updated my question. and I am not in strict mode, if I use the strict mode, two example throw the same `ReferenceError` at line 1.

Comment: @TiiJ7 ok，I just want to figure out how to explain the wonky performance，is it a Bug of JavaScript？

Answer (score 2):

Because your function `b` gets hoisted. AS soon its reaches `b = 4` a value is assigned to it.