# Functions that return a function, that is in it declared

Tags: javascript

I'm a little bit confused with this response.

```js
foo = "ffsds";
function bar() {
    return foo;
    var foo = 10;
    function foo() { return "func"; };
    foo = "5353";
}
console.log(typeof bar());
```

After executing this code I have seen that it return a **function**. But it is not clear to me. Why does it not return 10?

Comment: This is due to _hoisting_. Not quite a duplicate question but close: [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting)

Answer (score 4):

This is because of JS [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). As mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#order-of-precedence),

> ### Order of precedence
>
> It’s important to keep a few things in mind when declaring
> JavaScript functions and variables.
>
> 1. Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration
> 2. Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations
>
> > Function declarations are hoisted over variable declarations but
> > not over variable assignments.

Notice this part specially,

***Function declarations are hoisted over variable declarations but not over variable assignments.***

After hoisting your code will execute like:

```js
foo = "ffsds";
function bar() {
    function foo() { return "func"; };
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    foo = "5353";
}
alert(typeof bar());
```

Answer (score 2):

This works because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).
Function declarations "executes" first. Than all other assignments.

But you wrote a `return` on top so only function declaration works, that's why you get function instead of other value.

Here is a simple example

```js
function test() {
  return a; // returning
  var a; // variable declaration, works despite the return, but a equals function a because function declarations take precedence over variable declaration
  function a() {
    return 1;
  } // function declaration, works despite the return, override a to be a function
  a = 33; // function assignment - not works because return executes before assignments. a is still the function
}

console.log(test());
```