# javascript hoisting: Explain the output

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let s = new Set("Foood");

console.log(s); //{}
console.log(typeof foo); // function

var foo = "string";
foo = 34;

function foo() {
  //some code
}

console.log(typeof foo); // number
```

I was going through a codebase and came across this sort of codebase, can anyone explain the output of "typeof" operator in this code. Why for the first time it gave "function" and "number" second time.

Comment: It's because of a concept called [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting).

Comment: @Reyno can u rewrite the code snippet after hoisting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested the snippet will be interpreted as following. As you can see the variables and functions get moved to the top.

However variables initialised with `let` or `const` will throw a ReferenceError if they are used before the point they were declared. More on that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted)

```js
var foo, s;

function foo() {
  //some code
}

s = new Set("Foood");
console.log(s); //{}

console.log(typeof foo); // function

foo = "string";
foo = 34;

console.log(typeof foo); // number
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in the comments, here is the function after hoisting:

```
function foo() {
  //some code
}

let s = new Set("Foood");

console.log(s); //{}
console.log(typeof foo); // function

var foo = "string";
foo = 34;

console.log(typeof foo); // number
```

`function foo() {}` is moved up to the top of it's scope - which, in this case, is the top of the page. When the first `typeof foo` is called, `foo` is a function. `foo` is then overwritten, and becomes 34. The second `typeof` returns `number` because `foo = 34`