# Project-level .eslintrc.js tyepscript rule not taking effect

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, eslint

I'm following along with [this Ionic/Vue 3 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR91nlwdHjk), but I'm getting this error when I serve the project:

[image]

It seems my project-level .eslintrc.js isn't taking effect. In it I have an override for that rule:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ["error", { "functions": false, "classes": false }]
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Here's the repo](https://github.com/mitya33/eslintissue) (I've omitted `/node_modules` to keep the repo size down.) As you can see from the erorr in my question, it's referencing the default ESLint config, and seemingly ignoring the overrides in my own ESLint config in the root of the project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ESLint config

The configuration you have is actually taking effect:

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ["error", {
      "functions": false,
      "classes": false
    }]
  }
}
```

Note `functions: false` isn't going to control the linter error you're observing because `fetchWeather` is technically a *variable*, and not a *function declaration*. If you add `variables: false`, you'll notice the linter error go away:

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ["error", {
      "functions": false,
      "classes": false,
      "variables": false, 
    }]
  }
}
```

But I would **not recommend** that because the linter error is useful here, as it's trying to prevent a bug that would cause a runtime error.

### The error

In `weather.service.ts`, the `export` at the top is referencing [`fetchWeather`, a `const` defined below](https://github.com/mitya33/eslintissue/blob/df7447b/src/weather/weather.service.ts#L14). `const` variables are *not* [hoisted like `var` or regular function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting), leading to the error you observed.

```js
export const useWeather = () => ({
    weather,
    fetchWeather
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
});

//  not hoisted above
const fetchWeather = async () => {
    const {coords} = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    const response = await fetch(`${weatherUrl}&lat=${coords.latitude}&long=${coords.longitude}`);
    weather.value = await response.json();
};
```

### Solution

Either move the `export` to the bottom after the `fetchWeather` declaration, or make `fetchWeather` a regular function for it to be hoisted:

```js
export const useWeather = () => ({
    weather,
    fetchWeather
});

async function fetchWeather() {
    const {coords} = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    const response = await fetch(`${weatherUrl}&lat=${coords.latitude}&long=${coords.longitude}`);
    weather.value = await response.json();
};
```

You'll notice in the tutorial video that is how they've written it:

[image: screenshot from tutorial]

Comment: Oh dang... yes, I remember now, I went against the tutorial and used an arrow function. Rookie error! Thanks.