# Arrow function using var keyword and regular function with same name confusion in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, var

Why this logs 1 ? It's confusing to me , can anyone please explain?

```js
(function(){

  var hello = () => {
    console.log(1);
  }

  function hello () {
    console.log(2);
  }
  return hello()
})()
```

Comment: hoisting FTW..... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations (statements that start with `function functionName(`  )get hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope, and assign to their function name identifier first, before anything else runs in that scope.. Assignments with `=` do not.

The fact that it's an arrow function doesn't particularly matter - a `function` assignment at the same point would produce the same results.

```js
(function(){

  var hello = function() {
    console.log(1);
  }

  function hello () {
    console.log(2);
  }
  return hello()
})()
```

Your code is equivalent to

```js
(function(){
  // hello identifier gets created at the very beginning
  var hello;
  
  // hoisted function declaration assigns to `hello`:
  hello = function hello () {
    console.log(2);
  }
  
  // assignment with =, not hoisted, assigns to `hello`
  hello = () => {
    console.log(1);
  }
  
  return hello()
})()
```

I'd recommend using ES2015+ syntax at least, which will help prevent you from making these sorts of accidents - it will forbid re-declarations of variables if you use `let` or `const`.

```js
(function(){

  let hello = () => {
    console.log(1);
  }

  function hello () {
    console.log(2);
  }
  return hello()
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because:

- Function declarations create identifiers (more specifically, "bindings") in the same binding environment that `var` declarations do
- A `var` declaration for a binding that already exists is not an error
- Function declarations are processed upon entry to the function or global scope ("hoisted"), so they assign to the binding first

So your code is creating a binding, assigning a the *declared* function to it, then overwriting that value with the arrow function. In effect:

```js
(function(){
    // Declaration of the var-scoped binding happens first
    var hello;
    // Then the function declaration is processed, assigning
    // the function to the binding
    hello = function hello() {
        console.log(2);
    };
    // Then the step-by-step code begins and processes
    // the assignment
    hello = () => {
        console.log(1);
    };
    return hello();
})();
```

---

Side note: `var` is effectively deprecated, there's no reason to use it in modern code. Instead, use `let` or `const`. They have more rational behavior:

- They're block-scoped, not function- or global-scoped (unless they appear at the top level of function or global scope)
- Repeated declarations are an error (including a `let` or `const` declaration that would conflict with a `var`-style declaration like a function declaration)
- At global scope, they live in an inner scope nested inside the global `var` scope, and they don't create properties on the global object

Your example would have given you a nice, useful error with `let` or `const`:

```js
(function(){
    let hello = () => {
        console.log(1);
    };

    function hello () {
        console.log(2);
    }
    
    return hello();
})()
```